# Программа не видит последовательность и выдает ошибку ValueError: max() arg is an empty sequence

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, index

Задача
Программа считывает последовательность цифр из файла(построчно) и выводит на экран самую длинную возрастающую последовательность, ее длину и позицию

Проблема: программа не видит последовательности начинающиеся с нуля

```
import fileinput, time,os,re,psutil
start_time = time.time()
lst = []
# СЧитаем файл
with fileinput.FileInput('111.txt') as file:
    for line in file:
            for i in re.findall(r'\d+', line):
                lst.append(i)
    # Список возрастающих последовательностей
    list1 = []
    # Находим самую длинную последовательность
    for number, i in enumerate(lst):
        temp_s=''
        fl = True
        buff = 0
        # Проверяем только если больше одного символа
        if len(i) > 1:
            for j in i:
                if int(j) > buff:
                    # Накапливаем последовательность
                    temp_s += j
                    buff = int(j)
                else:
                    # Не возрастающая последовательность
                    fl= False
                    break
            # Запомнили последовательность и её номер
            if fl:
                list1.append((temp_s, number + 1))
# Находим самую длинную последовательность
longest=max(list1, key=lambda i: len(i[0]))

print(f'Полученные из файла последовательнности- {lst}\n'
      f'Самая длинная восх. посл. - {longest[0]}\n'
      f'Длина последовательности - {len(longest[0])}\n'
      f'Номер последовательности - {longest[1]}')
process = psutil.Process(os.getpid())
print("Программа занимает ", process.memory_info().rss /1048576,"мбайт")  # in bytes
print("--- %s Секунд выполнялась программа  ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
```

файл 019 0123 01234 0123456 0123456789 I (like programing) (мне нравится программировать)

Comment: Я бы советовал удалить вопрос. Это дубль, по факту. На будущее делайте тестовые примеры сразу полными.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Построчно считать последовательность цифр из файла и вывести на экран самую длинную возрост. послледовательность](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1412054/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d1%87%d0%bd%d0%be-%d1%81%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%84%d1%80-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d0%b0-%d0%b8-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%8d%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd-%d1%81%d0%b0%d0%bc%d1%83%d1%8e-%d0%b4%d0

Answer (score 0):

Замена `buff =0` на `buff = -1` решает проблему.